# Django installed apps location for classes on system path

Tags: python, django, path

I'm using the Django Registration class, it's great, but the last version shipped with an issue and it's no longer updated

I've installed it on my path (downloaded it then python setup.py install) then added it to my projects installed apps

I'm on debian, and It's copied itself to /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/registration

So far so great, but editing (hell, even deleting) has NO effect on my project

I'm guessing when you include a class in the django installed apps it's copied somewhere, but where?

As always, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you try the following workflow:

- Create a new `virtualenv` for every project you start (use `--no-site-packages`)
- Install all your dependencies (including `django`) in the project's virtualenv
- Use `pip install -e` to install things you need to have an editable version of.
- Alternatively, fork the project, and install using `pip install -e hg+http://...`

Answer (score 3):

You could try the oldest trick ever to figure out where it's coming from:

```
import registration
print registration.__file__
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm guessing when you include a class in the django installed apps it's copied somewhere, but where?

That's completely a wrong guess.

A better guess is that your download directory is on your Python path.

Somehow you had two copies (or more) of the module.

You've deleted some, but not all of the copies.

Keep searching on your `PYTHONPATH` for all the others.  Search every directory in `sys.path`.

Note that `.pth` files in your site-packages directory are also part of your PATH.